# What is "pink sale"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Example:

*The number of reservations made in the 2015 Pink Sale increased 45% when compared to the 2014 Pink Sale; while room nights booked were up 24% year-over-year.*

[BTA: Pink Sale A Success; Reservations Up 45%](http://bernews.com/2015/02/2015-pink-sale-success-reservations-45/)

Is it a non-existing phrase made up by a corporation to promote their product, or it has a meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pun on [white sale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_sale), which originally was a sale on bedding, which is often white of course.  In a pink sale, ladies' undergarments are on sale.

Apparently, the Bermuda people are appropriating this already labored usage to mean a sale of anything pink, in this case, a trip to their pink-sand beaches.  Or perhaps they think they are being original.

Answer (score 2):

The "Pink Sale" is a marketing slogan probably specific to this campaign. As I read it, it refers to a sale (cost reduction) on travel to the "pink sands" of Bermuda.